# How to make logging decorator log the filename where it's used and not where it is defined?

Tags: python, logging

I use the `logging` module with the `filename` format to capture the log output of my code. This works fine, since now I always know from which file the message was sent. However, I have an indent logging decorator for which I would like to actually log the filename where it *is used* and not the module where the decorator *is defined*. Is this possible?

Here is a short example of what it is doing now:

### test.py

```
import logging
from log import logger
from log import indented

@indented('Here I start my method...', 'And here it ends')
def my_func():
    logger.info('Look, a message!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='LOG',
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d [ %(levelname)-8s] %(filename)s: %(message)s',
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    my_func()
```

### Log output

```
2018-07-27 13:27:15.541 [ INFO    ] log.py: Here I start my method...
2018-07-27 13:27:15.541 [ INFO    ] test.py: ---- Look, a message!
2018-07-27 13:27:15.541 [ INFO    ] log.py: And here it ends
```

Now I would like all three messages to contain `test.py` like so:

### Desired output

```
2018-07-27 13:27:15.541 [ INFO    ] test.py: Here I start my method...
2018-07-27 13:27:15.541 [ INFO    ] test.py: ---- Look, a message!
2018-07-27 13:27:15.541 [ INFO    ] test.py: And here it ends
```

### log.py

```
import logging
from contextlib import contextmanager
from functools import wraps


class IndentationAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def __init__(self, logger, extra):
        super().__init__(logger, extra)
        self._indent = 0

    def indent(self):
        self._indent += 4

    def dedent(self):
        self._indent -= 4

    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        if self._indent > 0:
            return '{i} {m}'.format(i='-'*self._indent, m=msg), kwargs
        else:
            return msg, kwargs

logger = IndentationAdapter(logging.getLogger(), {})

@contextmanager
def indent_logging():
    logger.indent()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        logger.dedent()


def indented(begin_message, end_message):
    def indent_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            logger.info(begin_message)
            with indent_logging():
                output = func(*args, **kwargs)
            logger.info(end_message)

            return output

        return func_wrapper
    return indent_decorator
```

Comment: I noticed that in c:\Python36\Lib\logging\__init__.py it gets the filename from directly inspecting the stack in "findCaller" and it finds the first thing not in that file. Changing the logging module itself is right out, so I'm stuck there at the moment, and about to go to bed. The call through the adaptor happens in log.py but it finds test.py anyway. There might be a work-around defining your own format variable and pass it in extra.

Comment: incidentally, I found it easier to use stream=sys.stdout while debugging

Answer (score 1):

I was able to automate the filename and begin/end messages by copying some of the code inspection used by the standard library's logging module. I removed the manual begin and end messages, thinking this was more your intent. I also removed filename from the log format, and added it in the text logged by the indent_decorator.

```
    def indented():
        def indent_decorator(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                filename = os.path.basename(func.__code__.co_filename)
                logger.info(filename + ': begin ' + func.__name__)
                with indent_logging():
                    output = func(*args, **kwargs)
                logger.info(filename + ': end ' + func.__name__)

                return output

            return func_wrapper
        return indent_decorator
```

Here is the log output

```
2018-12-31 08:14:25.536 [ INFO    ] test.py: begin my_func
2018-12-31 08:14:25.536 [ INFO    ] ---- Look, a message!
2018-12-31 08:14:25.536 [ INFO    ] test.py: end my_func
```

I don't know how much we can rely on **code** staying the same in future versions of python, but this works for me in 3.6.5

I suspect that it should be further simplified so you don't have to put parens on the decorator, so that might be a later edit.